# How to change legend shapes when using geom_sf?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I'm plotting points using `geom_sf` and `ggplot`, and would like to change the shape of the points. I can change them on the map, but the legend never reflects the shape of the points, even when using `override.aes`.

I can't tell if I'm missing something or if this is a bug.  I've traced similar issues in the Tidyverse issue tracker, and [this one](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2211) is quite similar. But none of the ["resolved"](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2037) issues seem to address my problem.

Here is an example showing how `ggplot` fails to propagate the shape to the legend.

```r
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

cities <- tibble::tribble(
  ~ lon,    ~ lat,    ~ name,      ~ pop,
  5.121420, 52.09074, "Utrecht",   311367,
  6.566502, 53.21938, "Groningen", 189991,
  4.895168, 52.37022, "Amsterdam", 779808 
) %>% sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326)

lines_sfc <- sf::st_sfc(list(
  sf::st_linestring(rbind(cities$geometry[[1]], cities$geometry[[2]])),
  sf::st_linestring(rbind(cities$geometry[[2]], cities$geometry[[3]]))
))

lines <- sf::st_sf(
  id = 1:2,
  size = c(10,50),
  geometry = lines_sfc,
  crs = 4326
)

ggplot(cities) +
  geom_sf(aes(shape = name))

ggplot(cities) + 
  geom_sf(aes(shape = name)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(1:3),
                     guide = guide_legend(
                       override.aes = list(shape = c(1:3))))
```

[image: ggplot output]

I would expect the legend entries to have the same shapes as the map, but instead I get empty squares.

Comment: running your exact code: `Error: stat_sf requires the following missing aesthetics: geometry`  - peculiar. I added aes(geometry = geometry) and it works. shrug

Comment: The github thread which you have pointed towards seems spot on. It looks as if this is an unresolved issue with `geom_sf`. I think the way to go would be either not specifying `scale_shape` manually and use @markhogue's solution, or , if you really want to shape the points to your liking, use another function/geom to create your plot , or, the easiest hack, make a fake legend (make a plot and combine it with the main plot using e.g. cowplot or patchwork)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = cities, aes(shape = name), show.legend = "point") +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(1, 2, 3))
```

[image]

Comment: this doesn't work for the OP example when manually changing the shape of the points

Comment: That did work for me and I added `theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = NA))` to remove the grey background.

Comment: ah great, I did not think of that :)